# Как осуществлять бэкап базы MySQL на Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Как проще всего ежедневно (например, в полночь) автоматически проводить бэкап базы? Нужны ли что-нибудь устанавливать для этого или можно обойтись штатными средствами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне  достаточно стандартных средств:

1. cron -  для запуска по расписанию
2. И для снятия копии с баз(ы) -  mysqldump или mysqlhotcopy

Comment: Удобная обертка над mysqldump: [AutoMySQLBackup][1].[1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/